# ResizeObserverWrapper - Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I'm using React 16.13.0 and ant-design 4.4.1 and one of the tables has vertical and horizontal scrolling and when I scroll to 80% in Google Chrome, I'm getting the following issue. This is working fine in Firefox. How do I resolve it?

```
Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
▶ 3 stack frames were collapsed.
(anonymous function)
C:/path/src/app/components/GenericTable/Table/index.tsx:37
  34 | 
  35 | const handleRefChange = useCallback(scrollHeight => {
  36 |  if (!isNaN(scrollHeight) && scrollHeight > 0) {
> 37 |      setScrollBar(scrollHeight);
     | ^  38 |  }
  39 |  return () => {
  40 |      setScrollBar(0);
View compiled
(anonymous function)
C:/path/src/app/components/GenericTable/ResizeObserverWrapper/index.tsx:24
  21 |      const headerHeight = getElementSize(header).height;
  22 |      const paginationHeight = getElementSize(pagination).height;
  23 | 
> 24 |      onRefChange(containerHeight - headerHeight - paginationHeight);
     | ^  25 |  }
  26 |  // eslint-disable-next-line
  27 | }, []);
View compiled
▶ 27 stack frames were collapsed.
(anonymous function)
C:/path/src/immutableStateInvariantMiddleware.ts:243
  240 |        )
  241 |      })
  242 | 
> 243 |      const dispatchedAction = next(action)
      | ^  244 | 
  245 |      measureUtils.measureTime(() => {
  246 |        state = getState()
View compiled
```

### src/app/components/GenericTable/Table/index.tsx

```
import { Table as TableAntd } from 'antd';
import { TableProps } from 'antd/lib/table';
import { FilterEmpty } from 'app/components/FilterEmpty';
import { translations } from 'locales/i18n';
import React, { useCallback, useState } from 'react';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import { ResizeObserverWrapper } from '../ResizeObserverWrapper';

// Scroll property is managed by the component
interface Props extends Omit<TableProps<any>, 'scroll' | 'dataSource'> {
    rowKey?: any;
    useVirtualScroll?: boolean;
    otherClassName?: string;
    selectedFilters?: object;
    emptyText?: string;
    data: any[];
}

export const Table = (props: Props) => {
    const { data, loading = false, pagination, otherClassName, emptyText, selectedFilters = {}, rowKey = 'id', useVirtualScroll = true } = props;

    const { t: translate } = useTranslation();

    const [scrollbar, setScrollBar] = useState<number | undefined>(undefined);

    const getEmptyMessage = () => {
        if (!loading) {
            if (Object.values(selectedFilters).some(filter => !!filter)) {
                return <FilterEmpty description={emptyText} />;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    const handleRefChange = useCallback(scrollHeight => {
        if (!isNaN(scrollHeight) && scrollHeight > 0) {
            setScrollBar(scrollHeight);
        }
        return () => {
            setScrollBar(0);
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <ResizeObserverWrapper onRefChange={handleRefChange} containerClassName={otherClassName}>
            <TableAntd
                {...props}
                dataSource={data}
                rowKey={rowKey}
                scroll={{
                    x: 'max-content',
                    y: useVirtualScroll ? scrollbar : 'max-content'
                }}
                size="small"
                pagination={
                    pagination && {
                        showSizeChanger: true,
                        showTotal: (total, range) =>
                            translate(translations.app.components.GenericTable.showTotal, {
                                range1: range[0],
                                range2: range[1],
                                total: total
                            }),
                        role: 'table-pagination',
                        ...pagination
                    }
                }
                locale={{
                    emptyText: getEmptyMessage()
                }}
                data-testid="generic-table"
            />
        </ResizeObserverWrapper>
    );
};
```

### src/app/components/GenericTable/ResizeObserverWrapper/index.tsx

```
import ResizeObserver from 'rc-resize-observer';
import React, { memo, useCallback } from 'react';
import { getElementSize } from 'utils/helpers';
import './styles.scss';

interface Props {
    onRefChange: (any) => void;
    children?: JSX.Element;
    containerClassName?: string;
}

export const ResizeObserverWrapper = memo((props: Props) => {
    const { onRefChange, children = <></>, containerClassName } = props;

    const containerRef = useCallback(node => {
        if (node) {
            const header: HTMLElement = node?.querySelector('.ant-table-header');
            const pagination: HTMLElement = node?.querySelector('.ant-table-pagination');

            const containerHeight = getElementSize(node).height;
            const headerHeight = getElementSize(header).height;
            const paginationHeight = getElementSize(pagination).height;

            onRefChange(containerHeight - headerHeight - paginationHeight);
        }
        // eslint-disable-next-line
    }, []);

    return (
        <ResizeObserver>
            <div className={`resize-observer-target ${containerClassName}`} ref={containerRef}>
                {children}
            </div>
        </ResizeObserver>
    );
});
```